# Open Terminal From Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin to provide an "open terminal here" option when right-clicking on a folder in Eclipse? I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/), but it only seems to work on Windows, and I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Consider also [this solution][1], which relies on Eclipse Remote System Explorer.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console

Comment: in Eclipse-Preferences for tarlog 1.4.2 (which you linked to in your question body), I use this as "Open Shell command": `/usr/bin/nohup gnome-terminal --working-directory={0} &` , and for "Open Exlorer Command": `/usr/bin/nohup nautilus   {0}` . Works for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Easy shell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) definitely is the one you're looking for.

[image]

You can install it via Eclipse marketplace. If you don't have Eclipse Marketplace Client (e.g., you are using Eclipse Classic), you can install it: ["Install New Software..."] -->  search for "Marketplace Client"

Comment: Unfortunately, all I use is Eclipse Classic, which appears to be the only platform where Marketplace is unavailable.

Comment: @Chris S, it should work as well to directly add http://pluginbox.sourceforge.net as update site

Comment: highly recommending Easy shell, my eclipse's old friend.

Comment: easyshell works really good with Eclipse 4.2 and OSX 10.8.1 :) thanks!

Comment: easy shell is platform-independent, it launch system shell. It's excellent.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, here it is: http://code.google.com/p/openextern/

> This is an eclipse plugin, which you can use to open a shell (either a command prompt - CMD or a linux shell), or a folder (windows explorer, nautilus, konqueror) from eclipse's resource navigator or package explorer.

Comment: Installed it via Update Manager, restarted, but it had no effect...

Comment: Must have been a borked 3.4 Windows install. Tried adding it on a 3.5 Linux install, and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Atlhough this has worked well for years, I found it apparently doesn't work  at all in Unity with Eclipse 4.4. However, Easy Shell continued to work.

Answer (score 6):

To get an integrated terminal, try http://elt.googlecode.com

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, Thannks

Comment: I installed it Windows 7, but alas it doesn't work; should have read the fine print that said it won't not work for windows :(

Answer (score 3):

There is an Incubator project called Local Terminal. You can install it from the Eclipse update site under *General Purpose Tools->Local Terminal*
Much better then http://elt.googlecode.com

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know any plugin which integrates that, except for this one. You might be forced to modify tarlog.

I've had a look at the code of tarlog. You could have a look at the OpenCommandPrompt class 
(can be found in the tarlog package: tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2\src\tarlog\eclipse\plugins\openwe)

```
   @Override
    protected void doAction(String path) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.isFile()) {
                File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
                if (parentFile != null) {
                    path = parentFile.getAbsolutePath();
                }
            }
            if (command.indexOf("{0}") >= 0) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(MessageFormat.format(command, path));
            } else {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File(path));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

From what the code looks like it should work perfectly fine, as long as you specify the right executable in the preferences...

Answer (score 1):

Aptana 3 (base on Eclipse) has built-in terminal.
It is convenient.