# Open terminal or finder from Eclipse in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

After reading this question regarding Linux:

[Open Terminal From Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204403/open-terminal-from-eclipse)

I have the same question for Macs.  Is there a plugin available that lets me open a finder window or a terminal based on some folder in Eclipse?

Comment: This is a great question. Please reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[StartExplorer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/641101) opens the file explorer or the terminal in Mac/Windows/Linux.
Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace... and search for StartExplorer.

Updated jan-2015.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it out and it works like a charm.  Unfortunately, there is only an old style update site available.  So, I had to add this to the dropins folder, but it does seem to work.

Comment: It's also available in 3.6 (Helios) from Help > Eclipse Marketplace. Look for "ExploreFS". In 3.7M5 (Indigo) the marketplace was broken last time I checked.

Comment: Nothing comes up when I search for "ExploreFS" in the Eclipse Marketplace on Juno SR2.

Answer (score 20):

You can setup an external tool in Eclipse.  (It's the green RUN button that has a red toolbox).

Location:
    /usr/bin/open

Arguments:
    ${container_loc}

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Works pretty well for me.  I only wish there would be a way to associate a keyboard shortcut with the launch.

Comment: I was getting the error, "Variable references empty selection" until I put quotes around Arguments value like so: "${container_loc}"

Comment: Also, you may not have a "Program" option in the Run configurations. In that case go to the menu item Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration and it should be listed in the window that opens up. Once created you can run and configured it with the Run External toolbar button.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg. You can create a keyboard shortcut for the last run tool. Preferences -> Keys -> Run Last Launched External Tool.

Comment: Use ${resource_loc} to open the current resource

Comment: I'm a newbie to working with the Run Config .. it helped to know once I run that script, it A) now appeared in the Run-Configs drop-down & B) I don't even need the drop down if I want to just run the last Run-Config that was executed by just clicking the Run-Config button.  Then, for whatever is highlighted in Package Explorer, clicking that run-config opened a Finder to the selected location.  Nice solution - thanks!

Comment: add -a Terminal before ${container_loc} opens up terminal in the folder for me.  Now I have two external commands configured, one to open in finder, the other for terminal.

Answer (score 5):

[Easy shell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) that has most votes to the question you reference works on OS X, too.

[image]

You can **install** it via Eclipse marketplace. If you don't have Eclipse Marketplace Client (e.g., you are using Eclipse Classic), you can install it: ["Install New Software..."] -->  search for "Marketplace Client"

Comment: more votes for you, Sir! This is far better than the embedded terminal from Google and also opens Finder. Does the job of 2 plugins!

Comment: easy to install and easy to use, excellent !

Answer (score 2):

That could be (not tested) the [Open External Plug-in 0.7.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/open-external-plug)  (different from the [Google openextern project](http://code.google.com/p/openextern/) mentioned in this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204403/open-terminal-from-eclipse) you reference in the question)

See [how to install it here](http://pragmatic.kr/27).

[image]

Comment: Open External looks like a great plug-in, but unfortunately the update site that is linked to from the page is no more.

Comment: @Andrew: yes but you can download idrectly the plugin.jar at http://code.google.com/p/plug-ins/: http://plug-ins.googlecode.com/files/kr.pragmatic.openexternal.jar (and you can drop it in a shared dropins directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408961/upgrading-from-eclipse-galileo-to-helios/3409052#3409052)

Comment: And I also tried the Google Extern Project that you mentioned.  The plugin installs, but I get this problem when I try to go to the preference page:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Looks like it is compiled for Java 6 only.

Comment: Ugh...I hate using the dropins directory.  It has caused me no end of trouble in the past.  Maybe things are better now.  I'll try it.

Comment: @Andrew: you mean you don't launch your Eclipse with the latest JDK1.6 possible? (which doesn't prevent you to program in an JDK of your choosing)

Comment: I know.  It's a little more complicated.  I write eclipse plugins and the target environment must be JDK 1.5.  The best way to ensure that I don't accidentally break anything is to run under 1.5 myself (there are other things I could try such as setting my target platform to be 1.5, while using 1.6), but so far this has been the safest.

Comment: @Andrew: Easy: I never "install" the jdk I use for launching Eclipse: I only unzip it in a directory called "`jdk4eclipse`". I reference it in my `eclipse.ini` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) and that is the only place where that path is used. The rest (like a JDK5) is installed the usual way and referenced by variables like `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @Vonc I tried installing the jar from plug-ins.googlecode.com/files/kr.pragmatic.openexternal.jar in my dropins directory, but it didn't work for me with Eclipse 3.5.2.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't have the right configuration for me to test it directly. Can you reproduce that with more a more recent Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

*For a terminal to launch from Eclipse*

- in Eclipse, if you go to Help->Eclipse Marketplace and search for 'terminal', you will see this plugin from Google.  It launches a terminal inside in eclipse and to the location of the selected resource - does the trick.  I do think you need a later version of Eclipse for it though.

[image: Eclipse Marketplace Search for a Mac-friendly Terminal]

Answer (score 2):

There is an Incubator project called Local Terminal. You can install it from the Eclipse update site under General Purpose Tools->Local Terminal
Much better then http://elt.googlecode.com