# Eclipse plugin for recording time spent on given project/file/method?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Often I found myself working on 2 or more projects in one and the same month/week. Sometimes I am forced to switch between the projects during the day and it becomes a nightmare to record correctly hours spend on each project.

Is there a plugin for eclipse that will record time spent on given project/file/method? I imagine that it will contain some timer that counts time spent on each item (which stops when detects inactivity).

I know that such measurement will not be very precise but I don't need such a precision. I need something like a log:

```
12:45:01 - Opened project Proj1
12:45:03 - Opened file .../somefile.java
12:48:07 - Opened file .../someotherfile.java
12:50:22 - Focus switched to .../somefile.java
...
13:20:21 - Closed project Proj1
13:20:25 - Opened project Proj2
... and so on.
```

Such log will allow me to calculate how many time did I spent this day on proj1, how many on proj 2, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rabbit for Eclipse does that Perfectly.

http://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/

Comment: Great plugin. Too bad its development has stopped.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Mylyn + Tasktop have capability to [track your time](http://tasktop.com/resources/tutorials/MoreOutOfMylyn.php#WhereDidTheTimeGo) you spend on active task. I do not think it can track time spent on project/file/method.

In your case you you will have two different Mylyn tasks for each project and will activate them, time you spent on each of them will be recorder by Tasktop and it will provide you with time report.

Answer (score 3):

While not an eclipse plugin, [procrastitracker](http://procrastitracker.com/) records time spent by window title, which for eclipse contains the full path to the source file.