# Measuring number of file switches within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a possibility to measure the number of file switches a user performed within eclipse.
By file switches I mean opening a new tab or switching the active tab.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050800/eclipse-plugin-for-recording-time-spent-on-given-project-file-method) I have already installed [rabbit](https://code.google.com/p/rabbit-eclipse/), which is great, but unfortuately it is lacking of the above mentioned metric.

Does anybody know an easy way to measure the number of file switches within eclipse?